# SAFARI is downloading a .download file WITH NO CONTENT TYPE (EXPRESS, NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, youtube, youtube-data-api

Using express and ytdl-core (an NPM package to download youtube videos), i've been able to download mp3 versions of youtube videos for a radio like web-app i'm making. The only problem is when I try to download the mp3 with safari it starts downloading a .dms or .download file, not an mp3. It returns not content-type when downloading with curl.

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(cors());

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server IS ON !!! At port 4000");
});

app.get("/radio/download", (req, res) => {
  var URL = req.query.URL;

  console.log("A download request was received!");

  ytdl(URL, {
    filter: "audioonly"
  }).pipe(res);
});
```

I'm not sure how to get safari to reconize this as a valid mp3 file and treat it like so.

When I go to a link like `https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3` (A test mp3 file hosted on Internet Archive) safari shows a nice mp3 player: [image: a busy cat].

This doesn't happen with any mp3 downloaded using my express app.

**How can I attach the correct headers or what ever is neccessary for Safari to treat my mp3s correctly?**